# Ejercicio Numpy (Python)

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

Buenos días, tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio con python usando el paquete numpy del mismo (no me valen bucles ni nada por el estilo):

***Construir una matriz en la que el valor de los elementos sea igual a la suma de su fila más su columna.***

¿Hay algún comando de Numpy que pueda hacer esto?

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Miguel. Primero de todo deberias mirarte [ask] y [tour] para entender un poco el funcionamiento del sitio. Segundo, las preguntas que son tareas académicas para ser aceptadas deben venir acompañadas de una investigación previa, un resumen o el código de lo intentado hasta el momento. No existe un método en NumPy que directamente lo haga, no tendría sentido la tarea si así fuera. Debes pensar primero en el algoritmo y luego implementarlo usando los métodos que NumPy pone a tu disposición. Si intentas algo, edita la pregunta agregándolo y te ayudaremos. Un saludo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque se trata de una tarea académica sin mostrar la investigación previa pertinente o un problema concreto de implementación, de acuerdo a [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Usando `np.matrix` tendrías la matriz.
Como es un ejercicio mas matemático que técnico, te va a tocar resolverlo antes y luego modelarlo.
Te recomiendo esta [web](https://pybonacci.es/2012/06/11/como-crear-matrices-en-python-con-numpy/) para cuando crees la matriz